# read a html file from c++ without tags

Tags: c++

This code is supposed to read a html file in c++ and show the contents of the file without tags but it doesn't work. It doesn't show anything. Can anyone help me?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    string line;
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("ziba.txt", ios::in);
    if (!myfile)
        cout << "file cannot open!";
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        cout << line << '\n';
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        if (line[j] == '>')
        {
            while (line[j] != '<')
            {

                myfile >> line[j];
                cout << line[j];
                j++;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(line[j]=='>'){`  dont tags start with `<` and end with `>` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: After having executed the following sequence `while (getline(myfile, line)) {cout << line << '\n';}` the file cursor corresponding to `myfile` will have reached the end on the file. That means that the subsequent reads will have nothing left to process so your next while loop does nothing.

Comment: Problem 3:  `while (getline(myfile, line))` read all the way to the end of the file. Since the program is at the end of the file `while (!myfile.eof())` skips and removes nothing.

Comment: I'm going to risk [the wrath of the pony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You may be able to solve this with regex.

Comment: Read the file with `std::getline(in, text, '<');` and `std::getline(in, text, '>');` and print out `text` between each time.

Comment: @Galik  :sorry can you write the whole code you say?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("ziba.txt", ios::in);
    if (!myfile)
        cout << "file cannot open!";

    bool inside = false;
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        for (char c : line) {
            if (c == '>')
                inside = true;
            else if (c == '<')
                inside = false;
            else if (inside)
                cout << c;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now it can handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::getline` to read up to any character in the file so it doesn't just read *lines*, it keeps reading up to any character you tell it to.

```
std::istream& is = std::cin;  // or open a file
std::ostream& os = std::cout; // or open a file

std::string text;

// read up to the beginning of the next tag
while(std::getline(is, text, '<'))
{
    // print out what you have
    os << text;

    // read to the end of the tag
    std::getline(is, text, '>');

    // don't print this, it contains the tag itself
    // just loop back to reading up to the beginning
    // of the next tag.
}
```